# Ping a user defined IP-Range with batch

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, ping

I'm working on a school project and I wanted to create a batch file that pings a user-defined IP-range and writes the successful pings to a txt file.

Now I'm stuck at the `FOR` loop:

```
@echo off
SET /p IPRange=Bitte IP-Range eingeben(xxx.xxx.xxx) :
SET /p AnfangsIP=Bitte AnfangsIP des Bereiches eingeben :
SET /p EndIP=Bitte EndIP des Bereiches eingeben :

FOR /L %IP% (%AnfangsIP%,1,%EndIP%) DO (
    ping -n 1 %IP-Range%.%IP% | find "TTL=" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %IP-Range%.%IP% not reachable
    ) else (
        echo %IP-Range%.%IP% reachable
    )
)

pause>nul
```

The batch file is executed with these parameters: IP range, start IP-address, end IP-address. My goal is to make a `for` loop that increments the variable `%IP%` every loop. From the `start IP-address` to the `end IP-address`.

I searched in the forum but there are just single pings not for a whole range of IPs.

Comment: Delayed expansion problem.  Within a parenthetical code block, you need to delay the expansion of variables.  Otherwise, they keep whatever value they had at the beginning of the loop.  Also, the syntax of `for /L` is `for /L %%X`.  It's the double-percent, one-letter variables.  See `help for` in a cmd console for more info.  `for /L %IP%` is not going to work.  And finally, a `for /L` loop loops through *integers*.  It can't increment a fully-qualified IP.  It could increment the final octet if you wish, though, but only if you treat it as an independent integer.

Comment: Hello wOxxxOm. Thanks for helping me out. That with the one letter variable helps me a lot :) I will now look how to solve the integer problem. There must be a way to import the a string into a for-loop... :)

Comment: better check [portqry](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17148) tool provided by microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off

SET /p IPRange=Bitte IP-Range eingeben(xxx.xxx.xxx) :
SET /p AnfangsIP=Bitte AnfangsIP des Bereiches eingeben :
SET /p EndIP=Bitte EndIP des Bereiches eingeben :

FOR /L %%I IN (%AnfangsIP%,1,%EndIP%) DO (
    ping -n 1 %IPRange%.%%I | find "TTL=" >nul
    if errorlevel 1 (
        echo %IPRange%.%%I not reachable
    ) else (
        echo %IPRange%.%%I reachable
    )
)

pause>nul
```

**EDIT**: *Output example added*

```
C:\> test.bat
Bitte IP-Range eingeben(xxx.xxx.xxx) :127.0.0
Bitte AnfangsIP des Bereiches eingeben :0
Bitte EndIP des Bereiches eingeben :7
127.0.0.0 not reachable
127.0.0.1 reachable
127.0.0.2 reachable
127.0.0.3 reachable
127.0.0.4 reachable
127.0.0.5 reachable
127.0.0.6 reachable
127.0.0.7 reachable
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me ;(.  When I completed the 3 "sets" its just black and do nothing more ...

Comment: @LukasLustenbergerLoeschdu, what did you enter for the three `set`s?

Comment: Ok I didnt now what I did false. Now it works for me too <3 thx. I made a script without the for loop... But now I will take this :)

Comment: @Aacini IF ERRORLEVEL 1 then the PING didn't worked. In your Code you must write "IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1" or switch the content of the else and if...

Comment: @LukasLustenbergerLoeschdu: Well, you should realize that is _not_ "my Code", but an exact copy of the original code posted **by you**; I just modified the `FOR` command part as requested in the question: "Now I'm stuck at the `FOR` loop". If is there any error in the `if errorlevel 1` part, you should clear that this error is already present in the original code... **`:(`**

Answer (score 0):

He Guys

Thanks a lot for the answers. Finally the script of Aacini works. In time i made a script without any for loop that isn't that beautiful...

Here's the Code:

```
@ECHO off
COLOR F0

:START
BREAK>PINGLOG.txt

CLS
SET /P range=Bitte IP-Range eingeben(xxx.xxx.xxx):
CLS
SET /P sIP=Bitte Start-IP eingeben(xxx):
CLS
SET /P eIP=Bitte End-IP eingeben(xxx):
CLS

SET /P JN1=START PING FROM %range%.%sIP% - %range%.%eIP%?(Y/N):

CLS
SET /A counter=%sIP%
SET /A endIP=%eIP%
SET /A endIP+=1
CLS

IF /I %JN1%==Y (
    GOTO PINGRANGE
) ELSE (
    GOTO ENDE2
)

:PINGRANGE
COLOR 7C
PING -n 1 %range%.%counter% | find "TTL=" >nul
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
    ECHO ------------------------------------------------- >>PINGLOG.txt
    ECHO %range%.%counter% is reachable! >>PINGLOG.txt
    ECHO %range%.%counter% is reachable!
) ELSE (
    ECHO %range%.%counter% is not reachable!
)

SET /A counter+=1
GOTO CHECK
)

:CHECK
IF %counter%==%endIP% (
    GOTO ENDE1
) ELSE (
    GOTO PINGRANGE
)

:ENDE1
COLOR F0
ECHO -------------------------------------------------
SET /P JN2= FINISH! WOULD YOU SEE THE LOGFILE?(Y/N):
IF /I %JN2%==Y (
    START NOTEPAD "PINGLOG.txt"
) ELSE (
    EXIT cmd.exe
)

:ENDE2
COLOR F0
ECHO -------------------------------------------------
SET /P JN3= NEW IP-RANGE PING?(Y/N):
IF /I %JN3%==Y (
    GOTO START
) ELSE (
    EXIT cmd.exe
)
```

I now that this is not very beautiful :)

Have A Nice Day
Lukas