# Batch script with nested loops to ping range of IP's

Tags: loops, batch-file, nested, ping

Working 1 loop code:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,254) do @ping 131.212.30.%i -n 1 -w 100 | find "Reply"
```

Not running code where I try to use a counter so every time the ping gets a reply we add 1 to online:

```
SET online=0 for /L %i in (1,1,254) do for /L %j in (1,1,255) do @ping 131.212.%i.%j -n 1 -w 100 | find "Reply" SET /A online=online+1
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is this kind of what you're wanting to do? [Ping range of IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572939/ping-a-user-defined-ip-range-with-batch)

Comment: @bliziforst Sort of, but that doesn't really help me understand the nested loops and why they end up pinging a random IP. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Reply from 146.57.239.18: Destination host unreachable
```

The destination is not reachable, so your local host (146.57.239.18) replies with "Destination host unreachable").

146.57.239.18 is not the pinged host, but your localhost.

It's better to search for `TTL=` instead of `Reply`:

```
...
ping 131.212.%%i.%%j -n 1 -w 100 | find "TTL="
...
```

Also your `set /a online=%online%+1` doesn't work. You would need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). The `set /a online +=1` syntax works better:

```
...
ping 131.212.%%i.%%j -n 1 -w 100 | find "TTL=" && SET /A online +=1 || set /a offline +=1
...
```

As a result, the whole code would look like:

```
SET online=0 
for /L %%i in (1,1,254) do for /L %%j in (1,1,255) do ping 131.212.%%i.%%j -n 1 -w 100 | find "TTL=" && SET /A online +=1 
echo %online% hosts are online.
```

**EDIT** a much quicker solution (working parallel):

```
@echo off 
SET online=0 
for /L %%i in (1,1,254) do (
  start /min "pinging" cmd /c "(@for /L %%j in (1,1,255) do @ping 146.254.%%i.%%j -n 1 -w 100 | find "TTL=") >ping%%i.txt"
)

:loop
timeout /t 1 >nul
tasklist /v | find "pinging" && goto :loop
pause

for /f %%i in ('type ping*.txt 2^>nul^|find /c "TTL="') do echo %%i hosts are online
del ping*.txt
```

Comment: Suggested much quicker solution is good solution only to get OS frozen quickly. There is no upper limit of parallel running task.

Answer (score 1):

You have the syntax slightly wrong.  The following should work (split over a couple of lines for readability:

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,254) do (
  for /l %%j in (1,1,254) do (
    ping 131.212.%%i.%%j -n 1 -w 100 | find "Reply"
  )
)
```

Keep in mind that this is a lot of IPs to ping.